# Precision of Q31 and SP for FFT ARM Cortex-M7

Tags: signal-processing, cortex-m, fixed-point, fpu, cmsis

I would like to understand whether using fixed point Q31 is better than floating-point (single precision) for DSP applications where accuracy is important.
More details, I am currently working with ARM Cortex-M7 microcontroller and I need to perform FFT with high accuracy using CMSIS library. I understand that the SP has 24 bits for the mantissa while the Q31 has 31 bits, therefore, the precision of the Q31 should be better, but I read everywhere that for algorithms that require multiplication and so on, the floating-point representation should be used, which I do not understand why.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Getting maximum value out of fixed point (that extra 6 or 7 bits of mantissa accuracy), as well as avoiding a ton of possible underflow and overflow problems, requires knowing precisely the bounds (min and max) of **every** arithmetic operation in your CMSIS algorithms for every valid set of input data.

In practice, both a complete error analysis turns out to be difficult, and the added operations needed to rescale all intermediate values to optimal ranges reduces performance so much, that only a narrower set of cases seems worth the effort, over using either IEEE signal or double, which the M7 supports in hardware, and where the floating point exponent range hides an enormous amount (but not all !!) of intermediate result numerical scaling issues.

But for some more simple DSP algorithms, sometimes analyzing and fixing the scaling isn't a problem.  Hard to tell which without disassembling the numeric range of every arithmetic operation in your needed algorithm.  Sometimes the work required to use integer arithmetic needs to be done because the processors available don't support floating point arithmetic well or at all.